# '[String]' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: swift

I have added following code in appdelegate file..

```
func checkTextfieldValue(txtField : UITextField , placeholderText : String) -> String
{
    var varReturn : String = "0"
    if(txtField.text.isEmpty)
    {
        txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
        varReturn = "0"
        return varReturn
    }
    else
    {
        txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
        varReturn = "1"
        return varReturn
    }
}
```

and I have called that function in my other file

```
 var validText : String = [appDelegate .checkTextfieldValue(txtFirstName,placeholderText: "First Name")]
```

it's giving error. function should return "String" but it is returning "[String]".

I am new in swift. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you've created an Array with 1 String by calling like that.

The right way is to replace:

```
var validText : String = [appDelegate.checkTextfieldValue(txtFirstName,placeholderText: "First Name")]
```

by (remove [ and ])

```
var validText : String = appDelegate.checkTextfieldValue(txtFirstName,placeholderText: "First Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use it with [] symbols. Try to use it like this way;

```
var validText : String = appDelegate.checkTextfieldValue(txtFirstName,placeholderText: "First Name") as String!
```